# Blocking node creation after validation

Tags: 6, nodes, advertising

We have a lot of spammers (which are logged in users) creating content on our site. They are creating photo nodes without photos (which I have recently allowed as a way to catch them and ignore them, sort of a honeypot). I have also added the honeypot module but the 10 second delay doesn't seem to be working too well...

Is there a way to catch these nodes that don't have photos and block them from ever actually being created? I was thinking that it could be done in the `presave` hook, but unsetting the node didn't seem to work.

**Edit**

I could make the image required, but the bot is filling out all of the required fields so far, and it isn't hard to upload an image using a script.

I have implemented what I put in my answer and it seems to work, and I am giving the spammers 10 tries/day before they get banned. This may or may not be too lenient.

So far I have caught and banned 14 spam accounts (~1 hour of it being live).

Comment: Is there any reason you can't make the images a required field?

Comment: I would, but then they would upload photos. See the addition to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is the solution... doesn't create the node, sends them to a blank 403 page.

```
function _utils_photo_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $teaser = NULL, $page = NULL) {
  switch($op){
    case 'presave':
      if(empty($node->field_image[0]['fid'])){
        _utils_check_spammer($node->uid);
        //try again?
        die(header('Location: /node/add/photo', TRUE));
      }
      break;
  }
}
//meta code
function _utils_check_spammer($uid){
    if (in_spam_table && spam_count > spam_limit_for_today)
        //nice knowing you...
        ban_user($uid);
    else
        //you get some more chances
        increment_spam_count($uid)
    endif;
}
```

Comment: 264 spam accounts blocked, this seems to be a good way to catch them

Answer (score 0):

I think you should mark the image filed as required the bot won't be able to create the nodes without attached image.

Comment: I would, but then they would upload photos. See the addition to the question.

Comment: In this case, you should use drupal_goto() function instead of setting the header manually.

Comment: Ah, good point... I will do that